# Results based on two related criteria posgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

can sql search by two related criteria? If so, I would like to ask how to do it. I have two criteria, it is the personal code and the date of the personal code:

```
| Personal_id |    Date     |

| 12345       |  1/25/2022  |
| 1478963     |  5/13/2022  |
| 147895555   |  10/25/2022 |
| 98765432    |  1/25/2022  |
```

the table shows the personal codes and their signing dates. I need to find out the ID of the signed document, what it was when that particular customer signed with that personal code and that particular date.

There are about 100 options like this, so I want to know if it is possible to find that document id based on two criteria related to the personal code and date.

I don't need a complete request, I just need some function or logic to do it

Comment: Is this something other than an `and` conjunction in the `where` statement?  `select id from foo where personal_id = 12345 AND signed_date = '1/1/2022'`

Comment: But I need make for 100 unit's. and :
`where personal_id In (12345,1478963,147895555, 98765432 ) and signed_date ('1/25/2022',' 5/13/2022','10/25/2022',' 1/25/2022')` this dont work correctly, because other persons can signed in the same date

Comment: Aah, I see.  That's a much better question then.  Do you have permissions to create a temporary table?  Can you load these combos into a temp table and then just do an inner join?  If not, and it's messier, but you can join to `values`

Comment: IF you talk about `CTE` yes I can.

Comment: I have no problem if use `IN()` or some operator, I can change dates and id through in excel.
because dates and Personal_id i paste from excel, not database.

I just need the start logic with a couple of data, and later I will paste all the data I need from excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment, my first choice would be a temp table:

```
create temporary table dates (
  id integer,
  dt date
);

insert into dates values
(12345, '1/25/2022'),
(1478963, '5/13/2022') --  etc for the rest of your rows
```

Then you can:

```
select foo.*
from
  foo
  join dates on
    foo.personal_id = dates.id and
    foo.date = dates.dt
```

If you can't create a temp table, you can do the same with `values`, but this is ugly to me, especially as your list (100's you said) gets larger.

```
select foo.*
from
  foo
  join (values (12345, '1/25/2022'::date), (1478963, '5/13/2022')) dates (id, dt) on
    foo.personal_id = dates.id
```